# Static dropdown-menu doesn't work in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have a menu on my admin panel to navigate through the different functionalities an admin has on my website. I am using bootstrap and I found a static menu code snippet (so no dropdown) in the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/dropdowns/#menu-items

I am pretty sure my jquery, popper and boostrap js files work because my navbar works flawlessly. Am I doing something totally wrong here? You'll find the exact snippet of the bootstrap documentation in the body of my html.

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=./../dependencies/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css />

    <!-- Custom CSS (always after bootstrap) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=./../dependencies/css/style.css />

    <title>Admin - Paneel</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>

<script src=./../dependencies/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.js></script>
<script src=./../dependencies/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js></script>
</body>

    </html>
```

Comment: how do you want it to looklike???

Answer (score 0):

your dropdown-menu div should wrap in a
**dropdown** div

having a button

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
  </button>
<!-- your drop down gose here -->
</div>
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown">

          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>

      </div>
```

Comment: I know but I don't want a dropdown button, I just want a menu. If you look at the second code snippet of the documentation you'll see what I mean. I edited my code to be exactly what the snippet says.

Comment: try this      <div class="dropdown">

          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>

      </div>

Comment: For some reason the normal code works now. I had change my popper.js and bundle.js in my session, so maybe that had something to do with it. Thank you, yours worked too :)